# Redundant namespace qualifier on the call

Tags: c++, namespaces, argument-dependent-lookup

Why is **Categories**`::ff(Categories::a)` redundant?

```
namespace Outter{
    namespace Categories{
        struct V {};
        V a;
        enum class T { A, B };
        void f(T a);
        void ff(V a);
    }

    void f() {
        auto vec = vector<float>{};
        Categories::f(Categories::T::A); // Nothing redundant.
        Categories::ff(Categories::a);   // Redundant Categories quantifier
                                         // on the call itself.
    }
}
```

Comment: [No idea what you're talking about](https://godbolt.org/g/rQY14p)

Comment: @StoryTeller Yeah, though I didn't find it because I didn't know it was called that way. Definitely a duplicate.

Comment: BTW `Categories::f(Categories::T::A);` can just be `f(Categories::T::A);` as well